# Operador de comparacion operator==

Tags: c++, sobrecarga-de-operadores

Estoy intentado hacer un operador de comparación pero no se la forma de enfocarlo. 
La idea es que se pueda utilizar el operador == para comparar dos objetos de la misma clase, por ejemplo, tengo esta clase racional:

```
class Racional{
  private:
     int numerador;
     int denominador;
 public:
    Racional();
    void setNumerador(int numerador);
    void setDenominador(int denominador);
    int getNumerador()const;
    int getDenominador()const;
    bool operator==(const NombreRacional& r)const; //(Supongo que el valor de retorno será un bool)
```

Entonces ahora si yo quiero comparar dos numeros racionales:

```
if(Racional1 == Racional2){
...
}
```

No encuentro la manera de hacerlo, dejo lo que he intentado:

```
bool Racional::operator==(const Racional& r)const {
    bool resultado = false;
    if(r.denominador == denominador && r.numerador == numerador){
    resultado = true;
    }

    return resultado;
```

**Edito: El operador es correcto, el error venia de antes.**

Comment: Si tu clase se llama `Racional` ... ¿ Porqué en tu operador usas `NombreRacional` ? ¿ Y de donde sale `m_denominador` y `m_numerador` ?

Comment: error de transcripción

Comment: Un detalle tonto. No has puesto el motivo por el cual falla el operador ¿error en tiempo de compilación? ¿fallo en tiempo de ejecución? ¿Resultados inesperados?

Comment: La respuesta es igualmente incompleta porque no explica qué es lo que falla de tu código, luego que te funcione su respuesta sin más explicaciones no ayuda mucho

Comment: Es cierto lo que dices. El operador que puse es correcto, tenia errores "por delante" del operador y pensaba que el error estaba ahí. ¿Borro la pregunta?

Comment: Si ya no tiene sentido será lo mejor para evitar que se llene de guarrería. Por cierto, cuando respondas a alguien que no es el autor de la pregunta/respuesta, pon su nick seguido de una arroba @Chariot para que le aparezca un aviso y sepa que le has contestado

Comment: Por cierto, no vas a poder borrar la pregunta porque tiene una respuesta con votos positivos...

Comment: Voto para cerrarla en base a un error tipográfico, ya que no podrás borrar la pregunta al menos que no se llene de respuestas sin sentido

Answer (score 2):

Por costumbre siempre implemento el operador como una función (friend en caso de ser necesario):

```
bool operator==(const Racional& lhs, const Racional& rhs)
{
    // Acorto los nombres de los métodos
    return lhs.num() == rhs.num() && lhs.den() == rhs.den();
}
```

Comment: No explicas el motivo por el que falla el código puesto en la pregunta...

Comment: Por otro lado, la solución que pones no compilaría con el código de la pregunta...